# Speed limit for Google's PageSpeed API

Tags: google-pagespeed

I am running a Python script to make calls to Google's PageSpeed API and I am getting a really high error rate for my calls. According to the documentation I have been able to find, the API should be able to handle 100 calls a second and I have found that I need to limit it to closer to 3-5 to avoid errors.

I am fairly new to any type of coding so I am sure I am doing something wrong, but has anyone else been forced to limit the speed of their calls to avoid errors?

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve this ?
Show your code examples to limit number of requests.
Don't expect the community to do the work for you.

Comment: I recommend you reformulate your question to something other than "has anybody else experienced this?" - maybe along the lines of "what is the reason I'm experiencing this limit?" or "how can I increase my rate?", best combined with an [mcve] exhibiting the behaviour you observe.